# How to Test Move File in Java Spring Boot with JUnit

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit, integration-testing, move

I have a java Spring Boot application that looks for files in an Unprocessed directory, processes the file, then moves it to a Processed directory. I am trying to write an integration test in using JUnit that tests whether or not the move is successful.

To do this, I have created a sub-directory tree within `src/test/resources` that mirrors the directories on the servers. This way the test is not bound to any single computer or server.

When I try to run the test, I get the `java.nio.file.DirectoryNotEmptyException`.

Below is the entire text of my integration test. The idea is that I have a test file `test_file.csv` that permanently lives in my `src/test/resources` directory. For the integration test, I want to make a copy of that file, and write it to `src/test/resources/foo/bar/Unprocessed`. If the move logic being tested works, `test_file.csv` should end up in the `src/test/resources/foo/bar/Processed` folder. Both the `Processed` and `Unprocessed` directories are empty at the start of the test.

How can I make this test not error? Thanks in advance.

```
@Test
public void processAndMoveSuccessTest() throws IOException {
    File originalFileLocation = ResourceUtils.getFile("classpath:test_file.csv");
    System.out.println(originalFileLocation.getParent());
    String firstPart = originalFileLocation.getParent();
    String modifiedFilePath = firstPart.replaceAll("src\\\\test\\\\resources\\\\","src\\\\test\\\\resources\\\\foo\\\\bar\\\\Unprocessed\\\\");
    File unprocessedFile = new File(modifiedFilePath);
    Path originalFileLocationPath = Paths.get(originalFileLocation.getPath());
    unprocessedFile.delete();
    Assert.assertFalse(!unprocessedFile.exists());

    Path unprocessedFilePath = Paths.get(unprocessedFile.getPath());
    File processedFile = new File("src\\\\test\\\\resources\\\\foo\\\\bar\\\\Processed\\\\test_file.csv");
    Assert.assertFalse(processedFile.exists());

    Files.copy(originalFileLocationPath, unprocessedFilePath, StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
    Assert.assertTrue(processedFile.exists());

    int beforeProcess = repo.count();
    Assert.assertNotNull(beforeProcess);
    Assert.assertTrue(beforeProcess > 0);
    File testFile = importService.processAndMoveFile(unprocessedFile);
    int afterProcess = repo.count();
    Assert.assertTrue(afterProcess > beforeProcess);

    Assert.assertEquals(processedFile.getPath(), testFile.getPath());
    processedFile.delete();
}
```

Comment: From a testing standpoint, the only module you've placed under test is `Files`. I don't see any integration with your application here. While you certain are free to test a core Java library, I'm not sure how this benefits your application in its current design.

Comment: @Compass the link `File testFile = importService.processAndMoveFile(unprocessedFile)` is the snippet that is my integration test.

Comment: I may have misunderstood your use of the word "integration" here. Typically, integration involves external components like web services that you do not control. This appears to be a unit test targetting `importService`. From a testing standpoint, instead of creating a hard-path directory, you should use a temporary directory. Anyways, I think I see your error. `unprocessedFile` appears to be pointing to a directory, and if you attempt to delete a directory with contents inside of it without emptying it will fail.

Comment: @Compass I apologize for the terminology confusion, I'm relatively new to enterprise software development and test-driven-development. And thank you, your observation got me past the error. If you want to post your suggestion as an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most complex part with testing involving directories is that if your test unexpectedly fails or errors out, you will have a bunch of loose files that exist in your environment.

For sanity purposes, I would recommend using `deleteOnExit();` [as you create files and directories](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#deleteOnExit()).

This feature allows you to mark files for deletion upon completed execution.

```
File file = new File("test.txt");
Assert.assertTrue(!file.exists());
file.createNewFile();
throw new Exception("Foo");
file.delete();
```

This test can be run once, after which it will constantly fail on assert.

```
File file = new File("test.txt");
file.deleteOnExit();
Assert.assertTrue(!file.exists());
file.createNewFile();
throw new Exception("Foo");
file.delete();
```

This test, with deleteOnExit, can be run repeatedly without failing on assert.

In the event that you are creating a directory, it follows FILO.

```
File foo = new File("foo");
foo.mkdir();
foo.deleteOnExit();
File bar = new File("foo/bar.txt");
bar.createNewFile();
bar.deleteOnExit();
```

This will delete bar first, then delete foo. Foo will not be deleted if bar is not deleted, so follow the teardown by declaring deleteOnExit as you create resources and children.